# Webpack ignore file in source directory

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot

I have a webpack setup to compile my angular project. However, I have seperate main files for dev/mock/prod (`main.dev-only.ts`,...). When I try compiling, I get

> ERROR in : Type  in  is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in .../main.dev-only.ts and AppModule in .../main.mock-only.ts!
>
> ...some more irrelevant stuff

I've tried excluding the files I don't need using:

- `exclude` in module -> rules
- noParse in module
- webpack.IgnorePlugin
- specifying `ignore-loader` for `/.*(dev|mock)-only.*/`

but no matter what I do, I always get the same error. The only way to compile I have found up to now is to delete the unneeded files, which is not really a good solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

After some more trying around, I put the following two strings into the `tsconfig.json` `exclude` list:

- `**/*.dev-only.*`
- `**/*.mock-only.*`

This seems to work in this case, since no more complicated matches are required which use regex.